# Meaning and construction of "Ich bedanke mich"

Tags: accusative

I started studying German few months ago. I started reading "Der Nussknacker (Niveau Eins)". I found this

> Ich bedanke mich

but I can not really understand what does it mean and its construction.

Why nominative + verb + accusative?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It just so happens that the accusative declination of the pronoun **ich** is also the reflexive pronoun for **ich**.

The verb which you and many other German-learners perceive to be **bedanken** is actually ***sich* bedanken**, indicating it is **reflexive** and requires a **reflexive pronoun**.

"Ich bedanke mich" implies that you are saying "I thank you," even though the sentence doesn't contain an object.

If you wanted to be formal, you could say:

> Ich bedanke mich bei dir.

Comment: I updated my answer to try and give you a better understanding of what I meant.  Hope this helps!

Comment: I see. But why it wants the akkusativ and not the dativ? Also why the first and not the second person akkusativ?

Comment: You're getting confused between pronouns and the declension of nouns.  It doesn't take the accusative.  It requires a reflexive pronoun.  

If the sentence were intended to mean "We thank you," it would be "Wir bedanken uns."

Likewise, if it were intended to mean "You thank me," it would be "Du bedankst dich."

Comment: See the following articles on reflexive verbs in German: 

http://german.about.com/library/weekly/aa022601a.htm
http://german.about.com/library/weekly/aa022601b.htm

Comment: ok thanks for the Article. I was unware of the reflexive pronouns. Still I can't quite understand why mich and not dich :)

Comment: We do the same thing in English.  You just have to get used to it and take some time to understand the concepts behind what's being presented.  

When I say we do the same thing in English, we do.  Mich, dich, uns, etc., all mean myself, yourself, and ourselves respectively, in addition to being the accusative forms of ich, du, and wir, respectively.  :)  The goal here is for you to understand it, so do speak-up if you don't!

Comment: +1, concise and easy to understand.

Answer (score 2):

It is always like:

> Ich bedanke mich **bei** Ihnen *(someone)* **für** die Hilfe *(something)*

So you know that the someone (bei) is in *Dativ* and the something (für) is *Akkusativ*.